# Genymotion Android Emulater Disappear

Tags: android, ubuntu, emulation, genymotion

I installed genymotion android emulator on linux **Ubuntu 16.04** and download some virtual devices for it. After I start a virtual device, it disappears after 5-10 seconds. I tried some other api's and virtual machines and it's the same.

When I run the virtual device from **VirtualBox**, it gives me an error just like this picture:

[image]

Comment: Run it from Genymotion, not from Virtual Box

Comment: Yes i know , if i run it from genymotion it will disappear . i tried it several times with several different virtual machines . Thanks For Your Question!

Comment: Please describe what's happening in details. What do you do with the emulator? What do you mean by disappear?

Comment: I Did Nothing , Just Installed it and Downloaded the Virtual Machines And Started it Without Any Changes in Settings, the android machine will start and after some seconds it's disappears. just like it minimized . then ,  when i go to virtualbox i see the machine still work and when i click the show in the virtualbox , i see the error in the picture.

Comment: try enabling  VT-x. Also the new genymotion not working without opengl 2 enabled. So try to install your vga driver to the newest.

Answer (score 1):

I have the exact same configuration with Genymotion on a newly installed Unbuntu 16.04 box.  I came across the [this](https://www.genymotion.com/faq/#application-freezes) in Genymotion's FAQ section.  It appears that this can be caused by incompatible video drivers.  I'm running an Nvidia GeForce 210.  The stock Unbuntu install selected an X.Org open source video driver.  By going to Additional Drivers and selecting the proprietary, tested driver from Nvidia, I was able to correct this problem.  I did have to reboot after the changing the driver as well.

Comment: I had the same problem and it solution helped for me, but I have 3 different drivers:
- NVIDIA binary driver
- X.Org X server
- NVIDIA legacy binary driver
and it works only when I pick first one